# Color codes are shown instead of colors

Tags: powershell, cmd, colors, rust, rust-cargo

Whenever I execute `cargo run`, all colors in the console are displayed as color-codes. Other programs which display colors work normal and show the color.

When I redirect stdout like `cargo run > output.txt` all colors are shown just fine. This is the same for cmd, powershell and hyper (terminal emulator I use).

[image: color codes]

cargo 0.20.0 works as expected, but cargo 0.21.1 has the same bug as cargo@0.22.0.

I'm using Windows 10 16299.19. I'm not using the legacy console and I already deleted the `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` in the registry to reset the cmd colors.

I then tried it on an other account on my machine and everything worked. A clean install of windows didn't help.

Comment: This sounds like a change in the `cargo` project. Have you posted at https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/

Comment: Wanted to do this first, but I tried it on other devices with the same windows version (or lower ones) and it worked. I guess this is a problem on my pc, but I have no idea where it could come from. But thanks, I'll probably post it there too.

Comment: Well, I just tested it on another device with the same Windows version and it had the same bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue on Github](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4722).

The problem was the `term` environment variable which doesn't work properly with the [termcolor](https://crates.io/crates/termcolor) crate used by cargo.